# Visual Studio 11 & Metro App - Blue screen

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Visual Studio Express 11 for Windows 8 on the Consumer Preview. I am trying to developp metro apps but when I debug the application I just have a blue screen...
If I add controls they just don't show up even in VS11, they just seem to be invisible

Anyone experienced the same issue ?

EDIT : It is happening for projects created in C#, I have tested in Javascript and it worked fine

Comment: You're developing beta software using a beta IDE on a beta OS. There are bound to be a few bugs, and nothing's going to work perfectly yet.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a BETA group where you should be posting these bugs you find. After all, that's why you have the BETA software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. For those who might have the same issue it was because I had installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions (in order to have a shared folder with the host machine). I have just uninstalled it and now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem when running on Win8 in VirtualBox and also on physical machines with various NVidia graphics cards.  It seems to be an with certain drivers. On other machines the same binaries work perfectly.

Unfortunately all I can suggest is to try different hardware or see if there is an updated graphics driver you can try.

As a last resort you could try running the application using the simulator and seeing if that helps.  The simulator is effectively a remote desktop connection, but it may trigger a different behaviour in your graphics driver.